# Triple fault does not put system into reset

Tags: x86, x86-64, intel, hardware

Tried to issue platform reset via triple fault on my x86 based platform (Intel Cherry Trail x5 Z-8350), however platform just hangs. I see expected behavior on qemu - system reboots on triple fault.

Is triple fault a common architectural or specific micro-architectural thing available only on certain microarchitectures? Is there a cpu setting that prevents my platform from reset due to triple fault?

Answer (score 3):

A triple fault will put the processor in *Shutdown mode*, which is similar to the state after executing `hlt` but with a special bus cycle issued to notify the hardware.

So it's up to the hardware external to reset the CPU. Quoting the description of the Double Fault interrupt from the Intel SDM:

> If another contributory or page fault exception occurs while attempting to call the double-fault handler, the
> processor enters shutdown mode. This mode is similar to the state following execution of an HLT instruction.
> In this
> mode, the processor stops executing instructions until an NMI interrupt, SMI interrupt, hardware reset, or INIT# is
> received. The processor generates a special bus cycle to indicate that it has entered shutdown mode.
> Software
> designers may need to be aware of the response of hardware when it goes into shutdown mode. For example, hard-
> ware may turn on an indicator light on the front panel, generate an NMI interrupt to record diagnostic information,
> invoke reset initialization, generate an INIT initialization, or generate an SMI.
>
> If any events are pending during
> shutdown, they will be handled after a wake event from shutdown is processed (for example, A20M# interrupts).
>
> If a shutdown occurs while the processor is executing an NMI interrupt handler, then only a hardware reset can
> restart the processor. Likewise, if the shutdown occurs while executing in SMM, a hardware reset must be used to
> restart the processor.

Generally, a hardware reset is performed due to the last paragraph, however
Intel Cherry Trail x5 Z-8350 is a low-power SoC for mobile, it's possible some corners were cut.